# Is it possible to deactivate index in Firebird without dropping it?

Tags: sql, indexing, firebird, ddl

From the ib-aid link at [RDB$INDICES System Table](https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/firebird-language-reference-2.5/fblangref-appx04-indices.html) the RDB$INDICES has a column RDB$INDEX_INACTIVE column which indicates active/inactive status. Is it possible to modify this column to activate or deactivate an index. Could this be done instead of actually dropping/adding an index?

Comment: That link is an old version of the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference, I highly recommend you use the ones from the Firebird site ([2.5](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html), [3.0](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html), [4.0](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html) - links are for the single page version, see https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-rdbms/ for more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ALTER INDEX <indexname> {ACTIVE | INACTIVE}`, see the documentation for [`ALTER INDEX` in the Firebird 4.0 Language Reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-index.html#fblangref40-ddl-idx-altridx). This statement is available in all Firebird versions.

For `INACTIVE`:

> With the `INACTIVE` option, the index is switched from the active to
> inactive state. The effect is similar to the `DROP INDEX` statement
> except that the index definition remains in the database. Altering a
> constraint index to the inactive state is not permitted.

This last thing is important: you cannot do this for indexes backing a constraint.

For `ACTIVE`:

> With the `ACTIVE` option, if the index is in the inactive state, it
> will be switched to active state and the system rebuilds the index.

Altering an already active index to `ACTIVE` will also rebuild the index.